# is this the correct xml layout in magento 2

Tags: magento2

can you please confirm if layout xml of magento2 is correct.

This is layout xml of Magento1x

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
 <catalogsearch_result_index>        
    <reference name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <setTemplate>tagalys_search/filter.phtml</setTemplate>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

This is the corresponding layout xml of 2x

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_search/filter.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock type="catalogsearch/result" name="search.result">
            <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
                <referenceBlock name="product_searchlist_toolbar">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_toolbar/toolbar.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct block layout is below,
you have to remove `type="catalogsearch/result"` because type is not supported in magento 2. You can use class like,**`class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result"`** but in your case you havent required because you have already used **`referenceBlock`**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_search/filter.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="search.result">
            <referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
                <referenceBlock name="product_searchlist_toolbar">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_toolbar/toolbar.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Rakesh said, you don't need to add the block type (class in Magento 2) if you are referencing the block.

Also a few things I spotted:

- I don't think you need to reference each block like that (nested in content), you should just be able to reference the one block you're editing.
- You've missed out the closing page tag.
- Also `action method=""` shouldn't be used where the same results can be achieved with arguments. So I would switch the `<action>` tags with `<arguments>`.

Meaning the full code would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="catalogsearch.leftnav">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="setTemplate" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_search/filter.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product_searchlist_toolbar">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Tagalys_Tglssearch::tagalys_toolbar/toolbar.phtml</argument>
            </arguments>
         </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Thanks Ben , and jus to confirm , are action method="setTemplate" and argument name="setTemplate" same? and also is the referenceContainer name="content" not required? since i had used it in Magento 1x                                                                              Also in the 2nd referenceBlock action method not required?

Comment: 1. I believe so, I suspect the action tag will be depreciated in the future. 2. I don't think so, in my theme I have only directly referenced the container/block I've been editing. I haven't also referenced it's parent's and everything has work fine for me. 3. I don't fully understand the last part sorry, if you are changing the template you will need to use the argument (action method) tag.